# In VB.NET I am having problems populating a DataGridView combobox using a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have a datatable (dsBrands) that I want to display in a datagridview.  The combobox in the datagridview gets its selections from a different table(dsGroups).  How do I show in the combobox the value that is currently stored in the dsBrands table?  Below is my code that works except that the combobox is left blank.  The combobox collection does populate correctly from dsGroups.  The value that needs to be displayed in the combobox from dsBrands is in the collection.  The -->  is just to make the line stand out and not in the actual code.

```
Private Sub FillBrands()
    Dim TransCount As Integer
    Dim Group As String

    If Not ds.Tables.Contains("dsBrands") Then Else ds.Tables("dsBrands").Clear()
    conn.Open()
    daBrands = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Brands", conn)

    daBrands.FillSchema(ds.Tables("dsBrands"), SchemaType.Source)
    daBrands.Fill(ds, "dsBrands")
    conn.Close()

    dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    bs1.DataSource = ds.Tables("dsBrands")
    dgv1.DataSource = bs1

    Dim colDisplay As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    colDisplay.DataPropertyName = "Display"
    colDisplay.HeaderText = "Include?"
    colDisplay.Name = "Display"
    colDisplay.Visible = True

    Dim colGroupList As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    colGroupList.HeaderText = "Add to Group"
    colGroupList.Name = "GroupList"
    colGroupList.Visible = True
    colGroupList.DataSource = ds.Tables("dsGroups")
   -->  colGroupList.DataPropertyName = "BGroup"  'BGroup is a field in dsBrands table.

    dgv1.Columns.Add(colDisplay)
    dgv1.Columns.Add(colBrand)
    dgv1.Columns.Add(colGroup)
    dgv1.Columns.Add(colGroupList)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as when binding a regular `ComboBox`, you need to set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of your column.  The `DisplayMember` specifies the column whose values get displayed and the `ValueMember` specifies the column whose values correspond to the grid data.  `ValueMember` should specify the PK column of the table bound to the column that corresponds to the FK column of the table bound to the grid.